# What happens if an already excited electron gets hit by another photon (lasers)?

Tags: optics, laser

Slightly vague title but it is the best I can do.  My question stems from some interest in how  3 stage lasers function.  A photon from the pumping source comes in and strikes a atom in the active medium.  The photon is absorbed, an electron is excited,  and the energy instantly falls to a metastable state.  My question is what happens when I try to excite that electron again with another pump photon.    Does the electron jump to an even higher state if one is available (the pump photon provides the right dE again to excite the electron to a valid higher energy state)?  Or do we choose our active medium properly such that no "double-pumped" state exists and the excited electrons become transparent to the pumping photons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. If there would be a state available so that an electron in an excited state could be further excited (by the laser wavelength), this would also happen and reduce the efficiency of stimulated emission.

Hence, active media are chosen in such a way that this can not happen, or is at least at reduced probability.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wanted to double check.  Thanks!